# merging multiple strings into an argument

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am creating a warn command.
`args[0]` is the command, `args[1]` is the member to be warned. I want `args[2]` to be the explanation to be sent to the member. For example with
**>warn @member Spamming in chat** The member would receive  "You have been warned in  For: Spamming in chat".

> How can I dynamically merge multiple arguments into one?

```
//args[2] = <Reason>
<Member>.send(`You have been warned in @server For: ${args[2]}`);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
args[2] = args.splice(2, args.length).join(" ")
```

You can use [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods to merge strings to one.

```
args = ["warn", "@member", "Spamming", "in", "chat"];
args[2] = args.splice(2, args.length).join(" ");
console.log(args); // ["warn", "@member", "Spamming in chat"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple arguments: `args[2]`, then `args[3]`, etc... then use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `const [command, member, ...reason] = args;`

Then restore the spaces: `const text = reason.join(' ');`

Then `` message.channel.send(`You have been warned in @server For: ${text}`); ``

Full example:

```js
const args = ['warn', 'someuser', 'Spamming', 'in', 'chat'];

const message = { channel: { send: console.log } }; // mocking Discord API

const [command, member, ...reason] = args;

const text = reason.join(' ');

console.log(member);
message.channel.send(`You have been warned in @server For: ${text}`);
```

Comment: How would i go about this if i wanted the user using the command to be able to type anything not just "Spamming in chat"

Comment: @Elitezen you mean type multiple reasons for the warning?